# Ionic 2 & Firebase Infinite Scrolling

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am having trouble having infinite scroll work in my ionic 2 app with firebase.

This is my code to get the items from db

```
this.itemRef = firebase.database().ref('/Terms');

this.itemRef.on('value', itemList => {
  let items = [];
  itemList.forEach( item => {
    items.push(item.val());
    return false;
  });

  this.itemList = items;
  this.loadeditemList = items;

});
```

This is my html

```
<ion-content padding class="list">
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of itemList | orderBy: order" (click)="detailsSelected($event, item)" >
    <h2> {{ item.title }} </h2>
    <p> {{ item.desc }} </p>

</ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
 <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

I just want the ability to load the first ten.. then on scroll load another 10 etc...  the ion-infinite-scroll seems to be what I need, but it doesnt work with my code.

Comment: what is issue? is your infinite scrolling not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class would look like this (truncated):

```
class YourCmp {
    limit: number = 10;

    constructor() {
        this.itemRef = firebase.database().ref('/Terms').orderByChild('timestamp'); // or however you mark time
        this.itemRef.limit(this.limit).once('value', itemList => {
          let items = [];
          itemList.forEach( item => {
            items.push(item.val());
            return false;
          });

          this.itemList = items;
          this.loadeditemList = items;

        });
    }

    onInfiniteScroll(event) {
        this.limit += 10; // or however many more you want to load
        this.itemRef.limitToFirst(limit).once('value', itemList => {
          let items = [];
          itemList.forEach( item => {
            items.push(item.val());
            return false;
          });

          this.itemList = items;
          this.loadeditemList = items;

        });
    }

}
```

And your infinite scroll handler is obviously onInfiniteScroll()

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the following error : "Property 'limit' does not exist on type 'Reference'

Comment: Fixed, my bad @Misty

Comment: So it seems to work.. ALMOST... it loads the first ten.. the on scroll is  loads another 10.. then thats it.. it doesnt load anymore

Comment: nevermind! got it working by wrapping it in  setTimeout(()  ... now i just have to figure out how to get the scroll to stop firing after theres no more data..  I accepted your answer.. but let me know if you know how to make this happen

Comment: you could check the new array against the old array, and if they are the same, `*ngIf` the reloader out, or just tell the event not to fire

Comment: Thanks, ok one last problem i came upon ... my search filter doesnt work that great now because if i search something that hasnt been loaded yet, it says its not found. If you rather me create a new question you can respond to let me know!

Comment: You would need to add a separate server call for search, so you'd need to filter all your data for matching strings. This information exists somewhere on Stack Overflow. Essentially, you'd perform a query that starts with the string.

Comment: I am getting this.itemref.limit is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

For angular2/typescript ionic firebase app, the code below worked.
In the component,

**Import**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

**Declare**

```
limit: number = 10;
itemRef:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
itemList:any;
loadeditemList:any;
```

**Firebase Call**

```
getData(){
    this.itemRef = this.firebase.list('quote', {
      query: {
          orderByChild: 'title',
          limitToFirst:this.limit
      }
    });
}
```

**Scroll Call**

```
onInfiniteScroll($event:any) {
  this.limit += 10;
  this.getData();
  this.itemRef.forEach((itemList:any) => {
    let items:any = [];
    itemList.forEach( (item:any) => {
      items.push(item);
      return false;
    });

    this.itemList = items;
    this.loadeditemList = items;

    $event.state = "closed";
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-list>
...
</ion-list>

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="onInfiniteScroll($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Call getData() and inject firebase in  constructor.

```
private firebase: AngularFireDatabase
```